# How to make auto-type definition when serialize to xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

when I try to serialize data to xml I am using this helpful class: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx

So then I have:

```
public class LocalizableString : SerializableDictionary<string, object>
    {
        public object Get(string language)
        {
            return this[language];
        }

        public void Set(string language, string value)
        {
            Util.SetDictionaryValue<string, object>(this, language, value);
        }
    }
```

If I use usual code of this:

```
public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {

            XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
            XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));
            foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("item");
                writer.WriteStartElement("key");
                keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteStartElement("value");

                TValue value = this[key];
                valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
```

I wil get:

```
<PersonenListe>
  <PersonenArray>
    <PersonObjekt>
      <PropertyType>Unknown</PropertyType>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <FriendlyName>Max Man</FriendlyName>
      <City>Capitol City</City>
      <Age>33</Age>
      <Name>
        <item>
          <key>
            <string>test1</string>
          </key>
          <value>
            <anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p8:type="q1:string" xmlns:p8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">test2</anyType>
          </value>
        </item>
      </Name>
    </PersonObjekt>
  </PersonenArray>
</PersonenListe>
```

But I need to have the code with auto-type definition like above but without anyType code(ony with type of property) like in the next example:

```
<PersonenArray>
    <PersonObjekt>
      <PropertyType>Unknown</PropertyType>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <FriendlyName>Max Man</FriendlyName>
      <City>Capitol City</City>
      <Age>33</Age>
      <Name>
        <item>
          <key>
            <string>test1</string>
          </key>
          <value>
            <string>test2</string>
          </value>
        </item>
      </Name>
    </PersonObjekt>
  </PersonenArray>
</PersonenListe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your underlying Dictionary is typed `<string, object>`.  If your keys and values are always going to be strings, then change your first line from

```
public class LocalizableString : SerializableDictionary<string, object>
```

to

```
public class LocalizableString : SerializableDictionary<string, string>
```

And I would guess that this should resolve your problem.

Comment: but I will have different type of value, not always string

Comment: Ah, I see. Looking through the source code of `System.Xml` doesn't really seem to help me here, I'm afraid, so I don't really know. Sorry.